# Overlay calendar events not appearing in web part

Tags: web-part, 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I have got a site collection with a main site and a subsite for each client. On each subsite there is a calendar which contains recurring meetings. On the main site I have a calendar that points to calendars on the subsites and overlays their events however on the landing page I have added a web part and that only shows events of the main calendar and not of overlaid calendars.

Is there a solution to display overlaid calendar events in the web part?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I had the same issue, and I was able to achieve the end result I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you add a web part of the master calendar to a page, you have to switch to “calendar” view in the web part properties to see the overlaid items.

reference: http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/calendar-overlay-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-ootb-master-calendar/

Comment: I agree with this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even further - if you change your overlay structure - for example, change the color, or add another overlay - the webpart won't pick it up in my experience. You've got to edit the webpart again and reselect the view.